# Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `dead`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, deployment

I am trying to run "npm run build" in the cmd however I keep getting this error: "Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `dead`
at Array.forEach ()".

I have tried the solution that everyone says to implement online which is removing this part of from package.json

```
{
"browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11"
  ]
}
```

and creating a seperate .browserlistrc file which I then paste the above code into after it has been deleted from package.json.

However even after doing this I still get the same error so the solution does not work.

Anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the line "not dead" which would be like this:

```
"browserslist": {
"production": [
  ">0.2%",
  "not ie <= 11",
  "not op_mini all"
],
```

I'm not sure if this has to do with installing deprecated libraries